# Binary Search C# implementation

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-search

Here is one implementation I did for Binary search

```
public int FindIndexRecursive(int numberToFind, int[] array, int indexMin, int indexMax)
{
    if (indexMin > indexMax)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int mid = ((indexMax - indexMin) / 2 ) + indexMin;

    if (array[mid] < numberToFind)
    {                
        return FindIndexRecursive(numberToFind, array, mid, indexMax); 
    }
    else if (numberToFind < array[mid])
    {
        return FindIndexRecursive(numberToFind, array, indexMin, mid);
    }
    else 
    {
        return mid;
    }
}
```

it works fine.
I asked a question https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71815/binary-search-using-recursion-iteration-shifted-array

and I was answer that I can change my mid calculation

```
from: int mid = ((indexMax - indexMin) / 2 ) + indexMin;
to: int mid = ((indexMax - indexMin) / 2 );

public int FindIndexRecursive2(int numberToFind, int[] array, int indexMin, int indexMax)
{
    if (indexMin > indexMax)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int mid = ((indexMax - indexMin) / 2);
    //since the array is sorted
    if (numberToFind < array[mid])
    {
        return FindIndexRecursive2(numberToFind, array, indexMin, mid-1);
    }
    else if (numberToFind > array[mid])
    {
        return FindIndexRecursive2(numberToFind, array, mid+1, indexMax);
    }
    else
    {
        return mid;
    }
}
```

However now I get a stack overflow, what am I missing in my new implementation?

Comment: Did you mean to write: `int mid = (indexMax + indexMin) / 2` ?

Comment: @MichaelPetito I think this was my problem

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77896435/8644294) for the simplest implementation of recursive Binary Search using C# 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **might** have been advised that, to reduce the number of operations to compute the mid.

`(indexMax - indexMin)/2 + indexMin` **equals** `(indexMax + indexMin)/2`

Comment: @neo; they are by no means equal :P, different formulas, different behaviors.

Answer (score 4):

The original `int mid = ((indexMax - indexMin) / 2 ) + indexMin;` computes the distance beween `indexMax` and `indexMin` halves it and uses it to index the original array relatively to `indexMin`.

The new `int mid = ((indexMax - indexMin) / 2 );` is wrong and should contain a `+` instead of the `-`: `int mid = ((indexMax + indexMin) / 2 );` This uses the fact that mean of two values is just in the middle between them.

If you take a pen and write this and the original expression as expressions with fractions, you’ll come to the conclusion that they are equal:

```
indexMax - indexMin              indexMax - indexMin   2 · indexMin   indexMax + indexMin
------------------- + indexMin = ------------------- + ------------ = -------------------
         2                                2                  2                 2
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you take middle, is `(low+high)/2`.  Otherwise you'll get stack overflow exception.