# C# Binary Search of a number in an array using recursion

Tags: c#, arrays, recursion

So in the programming course I'm taking we learned about recursion. I got an assignment to write recursive function that gets sorted array and a number and return the index of that number in the array if existed.

I didn't quite understand yet the subject of recursion so I need a little help with my code. I think i'm at the right direction but again, I'm a little struggling with the subject so I thought I could find guidance and help here.

this is the code I have at the moment:

```
private static int arrayIndexValue(int[] arr, int ind)
{
    if (ind > arr.Length/2)
    {
        return arrayIndexValue(arr.Length/2, ind)
    }
    else if (ind < arr.Length/2)
    {
        return arrayIndexValue(arr.Length/2)
    }
}
```

basically what i wanted to write here is something like this:

if the number the user inserts is smaller then the middle of the array, continue with the function but with the array cut in half (Binary search)

same if the number is bigger (i suggested to use my function with something like the binary search but as you can see i dont quite know how to apply it to my code)

Comment: So you want us to write the code for finding index? Umm.. that's not happening unless you show what have you tried

Comment: First off when you write a recursive funtion you have to have one or more base cases that return immediately then you break down the problem into pieces that will led to the base cases  and then combine those results to return the result.

Comment: @Rahul Pretty sure they did show what they tried, which of course didn't work.

Comment: @Rhaul  I dont want you to solve my homework at all. how did you get that from my question?  what i want is someone help me understand a little better the subject of recursion so i could try and do my homework with some kind of understanding of the subject.  Second, i did show you what i have. the code i posted here is what i have so far (it's not much because i dont understand the subject yet)

Comment: "gets sorted array and a number and return the index of that number " I am not sure why the parameter is called `ind` is this supposed to be the number that is passed? and is searched for in the array?

Comment: @MongZhu yeah i saw it too now. i want to enter a number and search thru the array for that value.  and so my cutting the array part is wrong.  i want to cut the array if the value of the middle part of the array is bigger or smaller then the num enterd. but insted i check the index of the array with the value of the number enterd and that not right

Comment: Look at the Wiki article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

Comment: @MongZhu unfortunately it will take me more then that to figure that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i got an assignment to write recursive function that gets sorted array
>   and a number and return the index of that number in the array if
>   existed.

In your method you check indexes, not values - you should compare values of elements, not indexes.

To write recursive function to find element you should pass array, element to find, start index and end index. Start index and end index will be used for finding in part of array.

Your method will be something like this:

```
private static int GetIndex(int[] arr, int element, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    if (startIndex > endIndex)
    {
        return -1; //not found
    }

    var middleIndex = (startIndex + endIndex) / 2;

    if (element == arr[middleIndex])
    {
        return middleIndex;
    }

    if (element < arr[middleIndex])
    {
        return GetIndex(arr, element, startIndex, middleIndex - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return GetIndex(arr, element, middleIndex + 1, endIndex);
    }
}
```

and to get some index:

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    var arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    var element = 5;
    var index = GetIndex(arr, element , 0, arr.Length - 1);
}
```

Comment: ok it's looks just like the definition of Binary search.  but i got to write this kind of function with only a sorted array and a number.  could this be done with only those two parameters?

Comment: @Dolev, you should somehow know the part of array which you should search for element in so, you need 4 parameters.

Comment: ok, i tried to do this exercise with only two parameters so i guess that's why i was struggling with it.  i'll try to do it as all of you suggested with couple more parameters

Comment: @MongZhu oh sorry, jumped to conclusion to fast :P.  thanks again for the help! i will follow your advice and figure out the solution for this problam!

Comment: @Dolev When you have figured out one solution, I will post the entire code, so that you can compare. :)

Comment: @RomaDoskoch Thank you, i've based my answer to the assingment on your answer here.

Comment: @MongZhu hey, i've solved this assingment like Roma's answer here with four parameter. if you still want to compare solutions and show me how you managed to solved this with only two parameters: the array and the number it would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Recursion works by breaking the entire problem into smaller parts. If you are at the smallest part (meaning that your array has only one value) then you would have your solution. This would also be your first case that you have to handle.

```
if (arr.Length == 1) return arr[0];
```

Now you can start to break down the problem. Binary left or right decision. As you already wrote you want to check weather the number is left or right from the middle of your array. So in your condition you need to access the element in the array using the `[ ]` operator:

```
if (ind > arr[arr.Length / 2]) // check if larger than the middle element
```

To extract a part of the array you need a second array in which you can copy the content that you want. Since you intend to pass only half of the current array into the recursive call you also need only half of the size.

```
int [] temp = new int[arr.Length / 2];
```

Now you can copy the part that you desire (first or second) depending on your condition and keep searching with a recursive call.

To copy the Array you can use the [Arra.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft(v=vs.110).aspx) method. You can pass the start and length to this method and it will copy the left or the right part into the `int [] temp` array. Here is an example of how to copy the right part:

```
Array.Copy(arr, arr.Length / 2, temp, 0, arr.Length / 2);
```

In the end you will need to fire your recursive call. This call will expect the new array and still the same number to look for. So since you copied either the left or right half of the previous array, now you pass the new short array to the recursive call:

```
return arrayIndexValue(temp, ind);
```

And there you have it

Answer (score 1):

So the problem you have right now is that you haven't broken your problem into repeating steps. It actually should be very similar flow to a loop without all the variables. I want to do something a little simpler first.

```
void int find(int[] values, int at, int value) {
    if (values.Length >= at || at < 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if (values[at] == value) {
        return at;
    }
    return find(values, at+1, value);
}
```

This function just moves a index up one every time via recursion, but we can also do something very similar with a loop.

```
void int find(int[] values, int at, int value) {
    while (values.Length < at && at >= 0) {
        if (values[at] == value) {
            return at;
        }
        at = at + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The whole reason we usually talk about recursion is that it is usually used so that you have no "mutating" state. The variables and there values are the same for every value. You can break this, but it is usually considered beneficial. A quick stab at your problem produces something like

```
void int find(int[] sortedValues, int start, int end, int value) {
    var midIndex = (start + end) / 2;
    var mid = sortedValues[midIndex];
    if (start == end) {
        return mid == value ? midIndex : -1;
    } else if (mid > value) {
        return find(sortedValues, mid, end, value);
    } else if (mid < value) {
        return find(sortedValues, start, mid, value);
    } else {
        return midIndex;
    }
}
```

However, this isn't perfect. It has known issues like edge cases that would cause a crash. It should definitely be cleaned up a little. If you want to really want to dip your toe into recursion, try a purely functional language where you cannot mutate, like Haskell, Elm, or maybe something a little impure like F#, Clojure, or Scala. Anyway have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive Binary search using `C# 12` in `.NET 8`.

I'm using [Range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes) introduced in `C# 8` here. And using `NUnit 3` for testing.

```cs
public static int BinarySearcher(int[] sortedItems, int item)
{
    // Base case
    if (sortedItems.Length == 0) return -1;
    
    var midIndex = sortedItems.Length / 2;
    var guess = sortedItems[midIndex];

    if (guess == item) return midIndex;
    
    // Recursive cases
    // 1. Throw away the right half and search again
    if (guess > item)
    {
        var leftHalf = sortedItems[..midIndex]; // Upper index is not included, so it has elements from start to midIndex - 1
        return BinarySearcher(leftHalf, item);
    }
    
    // 2. Throw away the left half and search again
    var rightHalf = sortedItems[(midIndex + 1)..];
    var result = BinarySearcher(rightHalf, item);
    // The returned index should be offset by midIndex + 1 for right half search
    return result == -1 ? -1 : midIndex + 1 + result;
}
```

And test it like:

```cs
using NUnit.Framework;

public class DivideAndConquerTests
{
    [Test]
    public void BinarySearcher_Finds_Item_Using_DAndC()
    {
        // Arrange
        int[] myList = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
        var myListItem = myList[3];
        // Act
        var searchedItemIndex = BinarySearcher(myList, myListItem);
        // Assert
        Assert.That(searchedItemIndex, Is.EqualTo(3));
    }

    [Test]
    public void BinarySearcher_Doesnt_Find_Item_Using_DAndC()
    {
        // Arrange
        int[] myList = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
        // Act
        var searchedItemIndex = BinarySearcher(myList, 10);
        // Assert
        Assert.That(searchedItemIndex, Is.EqualTo(-1));
    }
}
```