# C# Recursive Binary Search

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

I'm trying to implement a recursive binary search for this `List<int>`

```
List<int> primes = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

Console.WriteLine(RecursiveBinarySearch.FindNumber(primes, 9));
Console.WriteLine(RecursiveBinarySearch.FindNumber(primes, 12));
```

Here's my Recursive Binary Search

```
public static class RecursiveBinarySearch
    {
        public static bool FindNumber(List<int> setOfNumbers, int targetNumber)
        {
            if (setOfNumbers.Count == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            int midpoint = setOfNumbers.Count / 2;

            if (setOfNumbers[midpoint] == targetNumber)
            {
                return true;
            }
                
                
            if (setOfNumbers[midpoint] < targetNumber)
            {
                setOfNumbers.RemoveRange(setOfNumbers[0], midpoint);
                return FindNumber(setOfNumbers, targetNumber);
            }
            else
            {
                setOfNumbers.RemoveRange(setOfNumbers[midpoint + 1], setOfNumbers.Count - 1);
                return FindNumber(setOfNumbers, targetNumber);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting

> ArgumentException
> index and count do not denote a valid range of elements in the List

in this line:

```
if (setOfNumbers[midpoint] < targetNumber)
            {
                setOfNumbers.RemoveRange(setOfNumbers[0], midpoint);
                return FindNumber(setOfNumbers, targetNumber);
            }
```

Here's a screenshot of the values of my variables in Visual Studio.
https://snipboard.io/iQ6ZIc.jpg

If you have run the code or viewed the screenshot, you can see that `midpoint` is `2` so both arguments for `RemoveRange()` are valid and within range which is why I don't understand why it throws the exception.

What am I missing?

Comment: The first parameter to `RemoveRange` should be an index, not a number of the list. Soo instead of `RemoveRange(setOfNumbers[0],...)` and `RemoveRange(setOfNumbers[midpoint + 1],...)` try `RemoveRange(0, ...)` and `RemoveRange(minpoint + 1, ...)`

Comment: Also notice that the second parameter is how many elements you want to remove. So `RemoveRange(midPoint + 1, count - 1)` will also fail, because you want to remove the half of the elements, not `count - 1` elements.

Comment: See the spec for details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removerange?view=net-6.0

Comment: Is this for educational purposes or something you would actually use in your app? Using RemoveRange would make it very slow.

Comment: Also, you should *not* remove the elements, since the calling code may not expect that unintended consequence and its bad practice.

Comment: `public static bool FindNumber(List<int> setOfNumbers, int targetNumber) => setOfNumbers.BinarySearch(targetNumber) >= 0`

Comment: Also: You check for Count == 0 , but you fail to check for Count == 1, which will also lead to an exception.

Comment: Hi Magnus, this is for educational purposes. Thanks for sharing the built-in binary search method :)

Comment: Hi Anand, I'll remember that. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi Fildor, that's what I noticed too. Thanks bud

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77896435/8644294) for the simplest implementation of recursive Binary Search using C# 12.

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not want to implement a search method that works by removing items. That will probably be much slower than just doing a linear search. It also modified the original collection, and that is typically not what you would expect from a method named `FindNumber`. You probably want to use a method that takes a specified range to search in as an argument. For example:

```
public static bool FindNumber(List<int> setOfNumbers, int targetNumber)
    => FindNumber(setOfNumbers, targetNumber, 0, targetNumber.Count);

private static bool FindNumber(List<int> setOfNumbers, int targetNumber, int startIndex, int count){

    int midpoint = startIndex + count / 2;
    var endIndex = startIndex + count;

   ...
    // Search lower range
    return FindNumber(setOfNumbers, targetNumber, startIndex, midpoint  - startIndex);
   ...
   // Search upper range
   return FindNumber(setOfNumbers, targetNumber, midpoint , endIndex - midpoint );
}
```

You might also consider returning the index of the found number, or just use the existing implementation of [BinarySearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-6.0).

You might also consider changing your input type to something like `IReadOnlyList<int>` or `Span<int>` to accept any kind of sequential list, and also to accept generic types with a `IComparer<T>` parameter to do the comparison, using `Comparer<T>.Default` as the default value if no explicit comparer is used.

Comment: Or maybe a Span<int>

Comment: Thanks JonasH. Learned something new :)