# Binary search with recursion c#

Tags: c#, recursion, binary-search

I got stuck with my binary search method and I don't really know what I'm doing.

At this moment I got

> 1 Error (CS0161) not all code paths return a value

```
int low = 0;
int high = cities.Length;

static int BinarySearch(City[] cities, int key, int low, int high)
{
    int mid;

    if (low > high)
        return -1; //Sökning EJ hittad

    mid = low + high / 2;

    if (key == cities[mid].temp)
        return mid; //Sökning Hittad!
    else if (key < cities[mid].temp)
        BinarySearch(cities, key, low, mid - 1);
    else
        BinarySearch(cities, key, mid + 1, high);
}
```

...searching for temperature with input from user.

```
Console.WriteLine("\n\tBINARY SEARCH\n");
do
{
    Console.Write("Search temp:");
    loop = true;
    str = Console.ReadLine();
    try
    {
        key = Convert.ToInt32(str);
        
         
        index = BinarySearch(cities, key, low, high);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Couldn't find any city with temperature: {key}°C");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Search results: ");
            Console.WriteLine(cities[index].ToString());
            loop= false;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Only numbers, please.");
    }
} while (loop);
```

Comment: You need to return the value from the calls to `BinarySearch()`, i.e. `return BinarySearch(cities, key, low, mid - 1);` etc

Comment: First of all but unrelated: Always use curly braces even on single-line ifs etc. Especially in the beginning this will save you headaches.

Comment: The `BinarySearch` method doesn't return anything in the `else if` or `else` blocks.  Hence, "not all code paths return a value".  The method has a return type, so every logical path needs to return something.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77896435/8644294) for the simplest implementation of recursive Binary Search using C# 12.

Answer (score 0):

The error message '`not all code paths return a value`' is correct:

```
if (key == cities[mid].temp)
    return mid; //Sökning Hittad!
else if (key < cities[mid].temp)
    BinarySearch(cities, key, low, mid - 1); // <-- does not return anything
else
    BinarySearch(cities, key, mid + 1, high); // <-- does not return anything
```

Fix:

```
if (key == cities[mid].temp)
    return mid; //Sökning Hittad!
else if (key < cities[mid].temp)
    return BinarySearch(cities, key, low, mid - 1); 
else
    return BinarySearch(cities, key, mid + 1, high);
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. 
But there's still one small problem with this code. 
When I search for a number that isn't an element in the array, I get "Only numbers, please." instead of "Couldn't find any city with temperature: {key}°C"

Comment: In that case, actually catch the exception thrown and look into it. But this should be a different issue, then. If you cannot resolve it, feel free to post a new question with the new issue.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but `int high = cities.Length;` might cause an [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.system-collections-ilist-item?view=net-6.0#exceptions). I think it should be `int high = cities.Length-1;`.

Comment: `int high = cities.Lenght -1` doesn't work well in this case.  But I've seen it before.

Comment: my issue is not an issue anymore. I dont know why but sometimes the program fix it self through a simple restart.