# Binary Search with recursive algorithm

Tags: c#, arrays, recursion, binary-search

Another problem here!
I've been coding a **Binary Search with recursive algorithm.**
Now it seems to be some problem when it search in upper half of the array. I can't really find whats wrong.

```
//=====Binary Search=====//
static int BinarySearch(City[] cities, int key, int low, int high)
{
    int mid;

    if (low > high)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    mid = low + high / 2;

    if (key == cities[mid].temp)
    {
        return mid;
    }
    else if (key < cities[mid].temp)
    {
        return BinarySearch(cities, key, low, mid - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return BinarySearch(cities, key, mid +1, high);
    }
}
```

When I search for a number that can't be found it will print: *"can't find temperature"*.
It is doing its work as long as I don't search for a number in the upper half.

```
Console.WriteLine("\n\tBINÄR SÖKNING\n");
do
{
    loop = true;
    Console.Write("search temperature:");
    str = Console.ReadLine();
    
    try
    {
        key = Convert.ToInt32(str);
        
        index = BinarySearch(cities, key, low, high);

        if (index == -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"can't find temperature: {key}°C");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(cities[index].ToString());
            loop = false;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Only numbers, please");
    }
} while (loop);
```

If I search for a number in the upper half, the console will print *"Only numbers, please"*. It goes to the `catch`-part. as it should if I search for something that can NOT convert to int.

Comment: You should [catch specific error type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) and print the error out while debugging rather than do a blind catch-all.

Comment: `low + high / 2` will calculate `low + (high / 2)` due to [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence) but you need `(low + high) / 2` in order to calculate the middle.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77896435/8644294) for the simplest implementation of recursive Binary Search using C# 12.

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence bites again.

How is the expression `low + high / 2` parsed?

Probably not the way you think. Multiplicative operators have higher precedence than additive operators, so

```
low + high / 2
```

gets parsed as

```
low + (high / 2)
```

rather than your intended

```
(low + high) / 2
```

Comment: Okey. This made it work to search for a number in upper half that's **IN** the array. But still if I search for a number that's **NOT** in the array, (searching upper half) the program ends upp in `catch { Console.WriteLine("Only numbers, please"); }`

Comment: How are you computing the initial value of `high`? The first element of an array `arr` is `arr[ 0 ]`, and the last is `arr[ arr.Length - 1 ]`.. if you are setting the initial value of high to `cities.Length`, you **will** get an index out of range exception.